# ConstraintViolationException при добавлении в базу hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

При добавлении в БД, выскакивает ConstraintViolationException
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс Agent:

```
public class Agent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "surname", length = 20)
    private String surname;
    @Column(name="firstname", length = 20)
    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "patronymic", length = 20)
    private String patronymic;
    @Column(name = "email", length = 50, unique = true)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "username", length = 20)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password", length = 100)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "age", length = 2)
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="user_roles",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "filiation_id")
    private Filiation filiation;
```

Класс Filiation:

```
public class Filiation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "filiaiton_id")
    private Long filiation_id;
    @Column(name = "name",nullable = false,length = 30)
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address",nullable = false,length = 30)
    private String address;
    @Column(name = "phone",nullable = false,length = 150)
    private String phone;
```

AuthController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    AgentRepository agentRepository;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;
    @Autowired
    FiliationService filiationService;
    @Autowired
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAgentDetailsService customAgentDetailsService;
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signIn(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginRequest.getUsername(),
                        loginRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);


        String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
    }
    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signUp(@Valid @RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpRequest){
        Filiation filiation =filiationService.findById(signUpRequest.getFiliation());
        Agent agent = new Agent(signUpRequest.getSurname(),signUpRequest.getFirstname(),
                signUpRequest.getPatronymic(),signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                signUpRequest.getUsername(),signUpRequest.getPassword(),filiation);

        agent.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));
        Role agentRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.USER)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("User Role not set."));
        agent.setRoles(Collections.singleton(agentRole));
        Agent res = agentRepository.save(agent);
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/agent/{username}")
                .buildAndExpand(res.getUsername()).toUri();

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new ApiResponse(true, "Agent registered successfully"));
    }
}
```

Вывод в консоли:

```
Detail: Failing row contains (5, null, null, $2a$10$VWqmBqq9MJSBwkX8n.RQwO2X2P4KWG5i0sSBOjipYMIuyIGaj//Ma, null, null, null, null).
2020-01-15 17:03:23.169 ERROR 16160 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [filiation_id]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "filiation_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (5, null, null, $2a$10$VWqmBqq9MJSBwkX8n.RQwO2X2P4KWG5i0sSBOjipYMIuyIGaj//Ma, null, null, null, null).
```

SignUpRequest:

```
public class SignUpRequest {
    private String surname;
    private String firstname;
    private String patronymic;
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Long filiation;
```

При дебаге вся информация коректно отображается в SignUpRequest, при внесении данных прямо в pgAdmin инсерт происходит без проблем.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте поставить аннотацию `@Transactional`, над методом в котором делаете сохранение

Comment: Не помогло с аннотацией.

Comment: Попробуйте дописать в аннотацию @JoinColumn(name = "filiation_id") `nullable = false`, может из-за разницы таблицы с сущностью.

Comment: Добавил в код, то что Вы просиили, пока выдает ту же ошибку.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить обратную ссылку с Filiation на Agent  `@OneToMany( mappedBy="filiation" ) List<Agent> agents;`.

Comment: Добавил, пока без изменений, таже ошибка

Comment: У вас проект на github?

Comment: Да, сейчас только запушу комиты в репозиторий

Comment: https://github.com/OleksandrKramer/InsuranceCRM

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103353/discussion-between-z-john-and-kramer).